# Is this a valid Gaussian Process kernel?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

$\mathcal{K}\Big( \; (x,y), (x',y') \; \Big) = \sigma_f^2 \exp{ \frac{(x-x')^2}{2l^2 \cdot (y+y')^2} } $, where $l > 0$

The variance associated with each training point *(given by a vector)* is a function of a co-efficient along one of the dimensions. This seems to point towards [heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity). However, the above kernel *(if valid)* looks like it would cover the property.

So, is the kernel valid? If so, does that mean I don't need to use a heteroscedastic GP framework to model variance as a function of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from a friend, I performed a quick test on MATLAB to check this. To find whether or not this was a valid kernel, I needed to check whether the resulting covariance matrix was positive semi-definite *(PSD)*. I used the following test.

```
clear;    
num_points  = 100;

xrange = [-100, 100];
% Sample from a uniform distribution in the given range
x = xrange(1) + 2 * xrange(2) * rand(num_points, 1);

yrange = [1, 20];
% Sample from a uniform distribution in the given range
y = yrange(1) + 2 * yrange(2) * rand(num_points, 1);

cov = zeros(num_points);
for i = 1:num_points
    for j = 1:num_points
        num = (x(i)-x(j))^2;
        den = ( ( y(i) + y(j) ) );

        cov(i, j) = exp(- num / den);
    end
end

eval = eig(cov);
min(eval)
```

In my case, since the smallest eigen value turned out negative, the matrix is not PSD.

**Note:**
This is a "rejection by sampling" test, and by itself cannot serve as conclusive proof that the covariance matrix ***is*** PSD, but in my case, since the result was negative, this was sufficient.

Comment: You have to careful with numerical issues here. I’ve seen similar tests “show” that the usual Gaussian kernel is not PSD. You are taking a bunch of exponentials and computing an Eigen decomposition of a large matrix, there is a lot that can go wrong.